# Polymer 3 in other project (like ASP.NET MVC) - create reusable components (PolymerElements)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, polymer, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create and reuse Polymer 3 components in ASP.NET MVC application. Right now I am not sure if I am approaching the issue correctly.

So first thing, I want to run everything from IIS express.

Right now I have this issue:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js".
> Relative references must start with "/", "./", or "../".
> ```

Here is my code:
**Index.cshtml**:

```
    <head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/PolymerApp/node_modules/@("@webcomponents")/webcomponentsjs/webco
       mponents-loader.js"></script>
       <script type="module" src="~/Scripts/PolymerApp/first-element.js">
       </script>
    </head>

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <div>
        <first-element></first-element>
    </div>
```

This is my **first-element.js**:

```
 import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

class FirstElement extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
      </style>
      <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>
    `;
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      prop1: {
        type: String,
        value: 'first-element',
      },
    };
  }
}

window.customElements.define('first-element', FirstElement);
```

I created this through cmd: **polymer init** and then chose element template.
When I run this through polymer serve on polymer`s localhost it works, so i guess there is some build process going on.

Thanks in advance. I hope that i described everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .js import path starts like this:

> from '@polymer/...'

Polymer 3 has a command "polymer build" that automatically translates the path to a real location:
Before:

> from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

After:

> from "./node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";

You can type ./node_modules/ in front to skip using the polymer build command line tool.

Comment: The problem with using `@polymer` and `@webcomponents` is that when used in Razor cshtml pages MVC tries to treat it as a web helper and fails.  The polymer cli doesn't know how to replace `@polymer` with `@{"@polymer"}` when building.  The closest I've come to finding a solution is to add the replace-in-file-webpack-plugin and add a rule to change the string.  However, I'm not having much success with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to do a string replacement in the polymer generated html file using webpack and a plug-in, but it doesn't seem to find the file.  Maybe someone more knowledgeable in Webpack-fu can figure out the rest.

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
const ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin = require('replace-in-file-webpack-plugin');

"use strict";

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: '/'
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./wwwroot/dist/[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/temp/"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 9000
    }, mode: "development",
    plugins: [
        new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([{
            dir: './path/to/polymer-built-app/build/default/',
            test: /\.html$/,
            rules: [{
                search: '/@webcomponents/',
                replace: '/@{\'@webcomponents\'}/'
            }]
        }])
    ]
};
```

**EDIT: 08/04/2018 **

I've figured this much out:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='Run - Development' />
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackStringReplacePlugin = require('html-webpack-string-replace-plugin');

"use strict";

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './'
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot'),
        filename: "./dist/[name].bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 9000
    },
    mode: "development",
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            "template": "./path/to/index.html",
            "filename": "../path/to/Views/Shared/_PolymerLayout.cshtml"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackStringReplacePlugin({
            '@webcomponents':
                '@Html.Raw("@webcomponents")',
            '%40webcomponents':
                '@Html.Raw("@webcomponents")',
            '%40polymer':
                '@Html.Raw("@polymer")',
            '/node_modules/':
                '/path/to/node_modules/',
            './src/path/to/polymer-app',
            '<!-- See google short url -->':
                '<!-- See google short url -->\r\n<base href="/custom/base/ref">'
        })
    ]
};
```